# Error when creating new SQL Database in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azureportal

When attempting to make a new Azure SQL database, it fails with this error:

> No default edition found under server version "12.0" (Code: 45122)

This happens when choosing either a "Blank Database" or the "Sample" Database.

Is there a place that I can set a "default edition"?

**Update**

I suspect there may be a bigger issue. When attempting to provision a new Azure SQL Server, the only regions available are shown here, whereas SQL Database should be supported in all regions.

[image]

Comment: I will report this issue to Microsoft Azure SQL Database team. Thank you. If you can provide me the region you are trying to create the database, please do. Thanks again.

Comment: The region is "Canada Central". I already have a couple of other databases on the same Azure SQL server in an Elastic Pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use Transact-SQL to create a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE hito   
COLLATE Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu_100_CS_AS_KS_WS   
( MAXSIZE = 500 MB, EDITION = 'standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S1' ) ;
```

Special Azure subscriptions may have limitations for creating databases on certain regions. East US is a region that does not have limitations for that type of subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks, @alberto. I tried in SSMS and got this:  "'Azure Benefits subscriptions are restricted from provisioning in this region. Please choose a different region. For exceptions to this rule please contact Microsoft Support.'"

Comment: I also tried using the AZ CLI and got the same errors.

Comment: Choose to create on another Region like East US. Some type of subscriptions have limitations on some regions. Are you using a MSDN subscription or Evaluation Subscription?

Comment: Yes, creating a new server in a different region (East US) worked and allowed me to create a database in it.

Comment: What is the name of the subscription you are using? I am glad it worked